# Put a checkbox in a cell in Excel v15 for Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to make a checklist in Excel.
Basically I am trying to make a cell:

[image]

Into a checkbox that can be checked or unchecked, and saved with the spreadsheet:

[image]

[image]

It's super-duper easy to do it in Apple Numbers, but very hard to do in Excel.
And exporting from Numbers to .xlsx doesn't support checkboxes yet.

I looked into "Cell Style" but it's not a cell style. I looked into Format but it's not a "format" either. I looked into "Insert", into "Page Layouts", into "Formulas", into "Data", I think I've looked everywhere, but I can't find this where I think it would make sense for this option to be.

Can it be done? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

In Excel 2016, instead of “Customize Ribbon”, you will need to go to the “View” pane in Excel Preferences, then check the box next to “Developer Tab”.

[image: Excel 2016 for Mac - View Preferences Pane]

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the File/Excel tab.
2. Click Options/Preferences.
3. Click Customize Ribbon.
4. Under Customize the Ribbon and under Main Tabs, select the Developer check box.
5. Go to the Developer tab - insert - and there will be a checkbox icon.

After you got the first one, you can copy-paste it.

Comment: No "Ribbon" option in Excel 2016's Preferences pane: http://i.imgur.com/utDT2uZ.png

Comment: @fabriced - Are you sure it is Excel 2016? Check the right side of the ribbon if there is a gear shaped drop down menu icon. Try looking for `Ribbon Preferences`.

Comment: This doesn't put a checkbox into a cell, it drops a floating checkbox on the workbook which you then have to drag and drop into the right alignment with the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I have Excel 2011 for Mac. I had to go to preferences, then click on Ribbon and click on the Developer. Once that is done. Click OK.

When you return to Excel, you will immediately find the Developer tab right after the Review Tab. Now you can do your check boxes, lists etc.